# Cómo puedo hacer que mi pagina de actualizacion en php no me vacie el resto de campos de mi BBDD

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo que hacer un formulario de actualización. Quiero que el usuario sea capaz de actualizar más de un campo a la vez de la base de datos. Pero como lo tengo hecho, inserta los datos del formulario y deja el resto vacios en vez de con el contenido que ya tenían. Quiero que se cambien los datos que el usuario quiera y el resto se quede igual. Habia pensado en añadir el select y que segun la opcion que se elija sea ese campo el que cambie, pero en este caso no sabria hacerlo. Mi código html es:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cambia un alumno</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <form action="actualizacion.php" method="post">
            <p id="creador">Número de Expediente del alumno a cambiar</p>
            <input type="text" name="nexpediente" placeholder="dawxxxx" required> <br> <br>

            <p id="creador">Actualizar Alumno</p>
            <select name="asignaturas" hidden>
                <option value="notaLM"> Nota de Lenguaje de Marcas</option>
                <option value="notaED"> Nota Entornos de Desarrollo</option>
                <option value="notaBD"> Nota Base de Datos</option>
                <option value="notaSI"> Nota Sistemas Informátios</option>
                <option value="notaPR"> Nota Programación</option>
            </select>
            <input type="number" name="notaLM" placeholder="Nota de Lenguaje de Marcas">
            <input type="number" name="notaED" placeholder="Nota Entornos de Desarrollo">
            <input type="number" name="notaBD" placeholder="Nota Base de Datos">
            <input type="number" name="notaSI" placeholder="Nota Sistemas">
            <input type="number" name="notaPR" placeholder="Nota Programacion"> <br>
            <br><input type="submit" value="Guardar" id="guardar">
            <input type="reset" value="Borrar" id="cancelar">
            <a href="eliminacion.html" id="eliminacion">Eliminacion</a>
            <a href="index.html" id="insertar">Insertar</a>
            <a href="consulta.html" id="consulta">Hacer consulta</a>
            <a href="tabla.php" id="ver">Ver tabla</a>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

y mi php es:

```
$conn= mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$clave,$db) or die ("Error en la conexion.");

$nexpediente = $_REQUEST['nexpediente'];
$notaLM = $_REQUEST['notaLM'];
$notaED = $_REQUEST['notaED'];
$notaBD = $_REQUEST['notaBD'];
$notaSI = $_REQUEST['notaSI'];
$notaPR = $_REQUEST['notaPR'];

$strSQL = "UPDATE alumno SET notaLM = $notaLM, notaED = $notaED, notaBD = $notaBD, notaSI = $notaSI, notaPR = $notaPR, promocion = $promocion WHERE nexpediente = $nexpediente";

$r=mysqli_query($conn,$strSQL);

if ($r){
    header("Location: actualizacion.html");
} else {
    print "<p>Ha ocurrido un error inesperado</p>";
}
```

Comment: todos los campos que sean obligatorio deben tener el atributo: [required](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) asi desde el mismo html se obliga al usuario a llenar todos los datos y no dejarlo en blanco... con esto garantizas en el fronend que se llene los datos.

Comment: ahora puede ocurrir que algun ocioso edite el codigo html para eliminar el required y bypasear el formulario... entonces en tu backend tiene que validar que el dato de ese campo no esta en blanco con una comprobacion condicional: `if(!isset($_POST['nombre_campo']) || $_POST['nombre_campo']===''){----Aqui metes el codigo para manejar el error ---}`

Comment: Ese no es un formulario de "actualización", porque no tiene ningún `value="dato_a_cambiar"`. Cuando el usuario pone el numero de expediente, el sistema debe hacer un SELECT y traer los datos para llenar todos los campos y así poder cambiar lo que quiera. Cuando le das `submit`, envias el *num de expediente* por `hidden` y vuelves a hacer el SELECT para recargar el formulario con los nuevos datos.

Comment: O si no (el comentario de aeportugal seria lo ideal) tenes que hacer un update selectivo que solo actualice los campos que realmente vinieron en la peticion... igual, lo ideal seria que hicieras una mezcla de las dos cosas... un select que traiga lo que estaba, un update que solo lo haga sobre los campos cambiados...

Comment: se puede verificar antes de guardar si los datos nuevos no están en blanco y son distintos a los actuales, y vas construyendo la query. O cargar los datos actuales con el numero de expediente y llenar los datos actuales en el formulario.

Comment: Vale, pues con vuestros comentarios y mezclando un poco de todo, he llegado a la solución. Basicamente he hecho un select y el php recibe el value del campo del select que se haya escogido y la nota y aplica la sentencia a ese campo. Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda ^^